# Prevent handler firing through parent element handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent the UL event triggering. I thought this could be done using the stopImmediatePropagation within it's parent container?

**html**

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>click me</li>
    <li>click me</li>
    <li>click me</li>
    <li>click me</li>
    <li>click me</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$('body').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $('div').css('background', 'black');
});

$('body').on('click', 'ul', function() {
  $('ul').css('background', 'yellow');
});
```

http://jsbin.com/yositusega/edit?html,css,js,output - if you click the UL, I want it so the div event triggers, and not the ul. So in this example the UL background shouldn't change color, but the parent DIV should. So black > dark red.

Is this possible to do through the DIV event handler? Would like to not have to edit the UL event if possible.

Comment: Events bubble up not down.

Comment: Why don't you just update the selector to be more specific?

Comment: @BenM legacy code.

Comment: And? What's wrong with adding a case to say on click of any `ul` immediately inside a `div`, don't handle the event?

Comment: You are catching ul click event, so this is normal that you receive ul click event. there is no problem here. If you dont want, just remove the ul click bind. If you dont agree, you should explain what you want.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the `ul` click is the legacy that you can't change. Now, you want to block this function and add your own functionality (`div` click) Am I right?

Comment: Logic doesn't make sense

Comment: Why would you place an event for ul at all then?

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

- Place the event listener on the parent (i.e. `ul`)
- In the event handler (`eventSignal()`), determine `event.target` by determining `event.targetCurrent` (which is `ul`)
- use `event.stopPropagation()` at the end of event handler.

## References

- [MDN EventPhase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase)*
- [W3Schools EventPhase](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_eventphase.asp)
- [Multiple EventListeners](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

*at the end of article there's a demo that might help

## Snippet

There's an extra utility function `evPhase()` I just added on the fly. I'm not sure if it is functioning correctly, but it doesn't hinder the main function `eventSignal()`. After observing the phases, I believe `evPhase()` is accurate, but there's not enough detail to show you that the `BUBBLING_PHASE` never reaches `<ul>` because of `event.stopPropagation()`...maybe if it was substituted for `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` the `eventPhase` might be `NONE`.. or it'll kill the whole process because the `event.target` isn't `event.currentTarget`....

Anyways, if you click the space surrounding the `<li>`, you are clicking the `<ul>` and not the `<li>`. Notice the `eventPhase` is:

> `AT_TARGET - The event flow is in target phase, i.e. it is being evaluated at the event target`

So it looks like `event.stopPropagation()` is stopping the `BUBBLING_PHASE` because if the event bubbled up far enough to `<ul>` then `evPhase()` wouldn't report `AT_TARGET`.

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');

ul.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  eventSignal(event);
  evPhase(event);
}, false);

function eventSignal(event) {
  evPhase(event);
  if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {
    var tgt = event.target;
    tgt.classList.toggle('on');
    tgt.classList.toggle('off');
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
  evPhase(event);
}

function evPhase(event) {
  var display = document.querySelector('output');
  var phase = event.eventPhase;
  switch (phase) {
    case 0:
      display.innerHTML += 'NONE<br/>';
      break;
    case 1:
      display.innerHTML += 'CAPTURING_PHASE - The event flow is in capturing phase<br/>';
      break;
    case 2:
      display.innerHTML += 'AT_TARGET - The event flow is in target phase, i.e. it is being evaluated at the event target<br/>';
      break;
    case 3:
      display.innerHTML += 'BUBBLING_PHASE - The event flow is in bubbling phase<br/>';
      break;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 3px outset grey;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 21px;
}
.on {
  background: yellow;
  color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
}
.off {
  background: #fd8;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="off">1</li>
    <li class="off">2</li>
    <li class="off">3</li>
    <li class="off">5</li>
    <li class="off">6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<output></output>
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```